# Indent lines matching a word, then print them with a replacement

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk, sed

I am trying to replace all occurrences of `open` with `not open`.  I want to print the original text with modified lines indented and preserved in original form followed by the modified form.

This command was not enough:

```
sed 's/open/not open/' file.txt
```

Sample input:

```
this is the first line of text
this text is very open
and this is the next line of text
```

Sample output:

```
this is the first line of text
    this text is very open
    this text is very not open 
and this is the next line of text
```

Comment: Please, try to be more clear. Edit the question to give a sample input and expected output.

Comment: OK, I see the input. Where's the expected output?

Comment: `sed '/open/not open/` would replace `not open` by `not not open`

Comment: And it would replace "very open" with "very not open", not "not very open"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed '/\<open\>/!b;s/^/\t/p;s/\<open\>/not &/g' file
```

Any line that does not contain the word `open` print as normal. Otherwise, insert a tab at the start of the line and print the original line, then replace all `open` with `not open` and print.

Answer (score 3):

Given this `input.txt`:

```
this is the first line of text
this text is very open
and this is the next line of text
```

The following code

```
sed '/not open/ b; /open/ { s/^/    /; p; s/open/not open/ }' input.txt
```

outputs:

```
this is the first line of text
    this text is very open
    this text is very not open
and this is the next line of text
```

The first clause merely skips any line matching `not open` (which means a line reading `The door is not open. Do open it.` has no replacement).  The `b` command skips to the end of the script.  You can omit this part if you don't want this logic.

The second clause keys on any other line's mention of `open` and performs three actions on it: indent by four spaces, print immediately, then make the replacement.  Finally, `sed` automatically prints the line (modified or not, even if already printed) at the end of its evaluation.

Comment: First, why do you answer a *question* which obviously doesn't fit the quality rules? Obviously because it isn't a question at all. Further note that your script makes `not not open` out of `not open`

Comment: I'm trying to be helpful. Rather than criticize the poster's English skills, I've guessed at the question and tried to give a useful and educational answer.

Comment: I believe that you had good faith, but you see it doesn't help much. Better would be to request more information and wait unless it will be provided (or not).. Btw, I would not criticize poor English because my English is also mostly incorrect. But IMHO it is not the English which makes this question a quality issue.

Comment: @AdamKatz thank you sir, all i want is to replace the word and print the original text and print it after i have replace the word

Comment: @odishoeivazi: If this is what you're looking for, please accept it as an answer. Otherwise, please clarify your question.

Comment: @hek2mgl I have addressed your `not not open` issue (as thoroughly as POSIX `sed` can). I also adjusted the question now that it has been clarified.